# Post head emotive modifiers

Tags: gramática, coloquialismos

Does Spanish allow post-head emotive modifiers such as *¿Qué **coño**?
¿Qué **mierda**?* and *¿Qué **cojones**?* after interrogative words in all cases?

Specifically is it possible when *cual* / *que* are followed by a noun, as in *qué cojones lapiz rompiste*?

Comment: Your examples show it does. I really don't understand what is the question here.

Comment: I don't speak Spanish, so I'm looking for confirmation because, in English, you can't say *what the hell pencil did you break*. I take it, then, that this is perfectly grammatical.

Comment: Ok. I get it now. Saying the sentence "que cojones lápiz rompiste" doesn't sound very natural. If what you are trying to say is "did you break the f@@king pencil?" a more grammatically correct expression would be **"¿rompiste el puto lápiz?"**

Comment: I think it doesn't (at least no in all cases), although more and more often I hear stuff like "esto es _puto_ peligroso" which I believe is some sort of anglicism, translating directly from "this is _fucking_dangerous"). I know it is not exactly your case "cual/que + noun" but I just wanted to mention.

Comment: @Diego about "puto peligroso", the Spanish Royal Academy has [something to say](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1136614469122084864)...

Answer (score 2):

I would say this kind of emphasis is only possible in a couple borderline cases.

First, the syntax. In sentences like

- *¿Qué mierda hiciste?*
- *¿Qué cojones te pasa?*

there's a free slot right after the interrogative word, that can be filled with a short expletive. This sounds natural in questions with *qué* because *qué* can also be followed by a noun phrase. It's not the same, because the expletive doesn't have to agree with the verb (in *¿Qué cojones te pasa?* the expletive is plural but the verb is in the singular), but it sounds a bit like that.

An expletive can also be inserted after other interrogatives, like *dónde* or *cómo*; in those cases its function is clear: it's basically a verbal exclamation point. It doesn't agree with anything, it's just something you drop there somewhere.

One borderline case is *qué mierda de* + noun. One could maybe say *mierda de* is an expletive.

- *¿Qué mierda de comida es ésta?*
- *¿A qué mierda de escuela fuiste?*

*Mierda de* + noun is an expletive in the sense that it emphasizes the whole sentence. Note the difference with the reversed pattern noun + *de mierda*:

- *¿Qué comida de mierda es ésta?*
- *¿A qué escuela de mierda fuiste?*

In the first two sentences you are mainly expressing shock or disbelief while also disqualifying the food or the school; in the last two you are actually asking about the food or the school. In English you'd translate both of these, I think, as "What kind of shitty (whatever)...?".

I'd say *puto/a* is another borderline case in questions like

- *¿Qué puto lápiz rompiste?*
- *¿Qué puta excusa vas a darme?*

Here you have a regular adjective agreeing with the noun it modifies, but at the same time it works like a true expletive: it doesn't mean anything, it just emphasizes the point of the whole question.

I don't think there are many more possible examples, but it depends on dialect, I guess.